# Java production: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException Unable to build SpringBoot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, jvm

I've launched my spring boot project, my computer suddenly shuts down (battery issue !)  Then I got the following error when trying to run the project again

```
Module 'ms-overdue' production: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Range [-1, -1 + 1025) out of bounds for length 1024
```

I tried to invalidate caches and restart again but it doesn't work ! any suggestion please

Comment: did you manage to find and fix without uninstalling and reinstalling?

Comment: I could solve the issue with "Reload All Maven Projects" action

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Such weird error! But it seems that it's an issue with InteliJ IDE due to the unexpected shutdown

In order to fix it, I to uninsatll and reinstall my IDE (an update maybe enough), then I got a new error

```
Maven resources compiler: Maven project configuration required for module 'ms-overdue' isn't available. Compilation of Maven projects is supported only if external build is started from an IDE.
```

I removed the project from history and I opened it again , finally I right clicked on `pom.xml`  >  `+ Add as Maven Project`

Comment: I could avoid uninstall/reinstall by simply removing `~\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.2`

Comment: Removing app data works Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Intellij Idea, it was enough for doing these to do Build -> Rebuild Project.

Comment: strange, mvn clean install didn't helped but build->rebuild project helped.

Comment: Yes. Some-time the code is also get confuse.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Intellij Idea, it was enough for me to do **Build -> Rebuild Project**.

Answer (score 0):

Take backup of the ***.idea*** folder from the parent/main module for safety and delete the .idea folder. Reload the project into intelliJ **New > Project From Existing Sources..** might fix the problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with IntelliJ IDE due to the unexpected shutdown
Go to File-> Invalidate Caches then select invalidate and restart.
Then maven build the modules and it will resolved.

Answer (score 0):

We can just right click on project and click on **REPAIR IDE ON FILE** then build all modules and then the issue will be resolved
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBgXO.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35213506)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the path to the project does not have any tags, preferably letters, because this problem appeared to me a while ago and I solved it in this way, for further clarification:

- The path is incorrectly named

> my/projects/java/Console_app

- The right track

> my/projects/java/ConsoleApp

Comment: Please use only English on Stackoverflow (see here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange). You could edit your answer to leave only the English part